# c# Database update and insert

Tags: c#

Im having a databse with some customer information (customer_nr(primary key), name, address and so on)

The informaton comes from an xml file and is stored in the databse called customer_info.
Now i want to update this table, example if the customer changes his address i want to update the table or, if an customer does not exist i want to insert a new row with the information. Now how do I do this? Ive tried alot of diffrent things but nothing seems to work.

example code:

my insert looks like this:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [customer_info] (custoner_nr, firstName,lastName, adress_1....(and so on))", connection)) {
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_nr", customerNr);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", fName);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lName); 
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

my update looks like this:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [customer_info] SET [customer_nr] = @customer_nr [firstName] = @firstName, [lastName] = @lastName, WHERE (([customer_nr] = @customer_nr))", connection)) {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custmer_nr", customerNr);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fornamn", fName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@efternamn", lName);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I've tried to match the `customer_nr`, something like this:

```
DataRow row = dataSet.custmer_info.FindBycustomer_nr(t.customerNr);
if (bla != null) {
   updateCustomer(t.kontoNr,t.fName,t.lastname....);
} else {
   insertCustomer(t.kontoNr,t.fName,t.lastname....);
}
```

If someone understands my problem and could help me i would be so greatful, im really stuck and what ive been testing does not work. =(

Comment: So, what _does_ your code do? What errors are you getting? What behaviour?

Comment: Are we doing your homework? :-)

Comment: How is your DataSet getting updated with the inserted or updated records? How are you determining that your code doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see you are not opening an closing the connection

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [customer_info] SET [customer_nr] = @customer_nr [firstName] = @firstName, [lastName] = @lastName, WHERE (([customer_nr] = @customer_nr))", connection)) {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custmer_nr", customerNr);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fornamn", fName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@efternamn", lName);
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try using an O/RM tool such as *EntityFramework*. you can [get started here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)